# What happens if I disable and uninstall Plymouth?

Tags: boot, plymouth

I have this problem with Plymouth, in wich it doesn't show up or, when it shows, with a awful resolution.

So, I wanted to uninstall Plymouth ( I found the package in Synaptics).

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, in dual-boot with Windows 7.

And I wanted to know:

- What happens if I uninstall Plymouth?
- Am I going to be able to boot to Ubuntu (and Windows 7)?
- Is my boot going to be faster?
- Can I reinstall it, if I want?
- Is there a better way to uninstall it?
- If I don't disable it before I unistall it, am I going to have trouble?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You don`t need too uninstall you can just disable it 
Try to do this in you terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it too :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

And update Grub(be very careful you can break your boot if power goes down or something goes wong):

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: you can`t uninstall it. it does also things behind the scene like react on a file system or decryption error but if you want you can uninstall  plymouth-label which does the graphical things of Plymouth

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. What happens is that the maximum resolution of my notebook screen is of 1366x768, but neither GRUB or Plymouth support it. I've already fixed GRUB with a resolution of 1024x768, but the same didn't work for Plymouth, wich just disappeared, or appeared with a strange resolution. Thanks!