# iPlymouth Broke GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

I followed the steps in this thread:
[What happens if I disable and unistall Plymouth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136280/what-happens-if-i-disable-and-unistall-plymouth/498101#498101)

Now GRUB is broken. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.4 without a GUI and when my server boots now, I get a screen showing what services are starting and then it says:

```
umount: /proc/fs/nfsd: device is busy.
```

When I press the arrow keys, it alternates from this screen and the purple Ubuntu splash screen.

Comment: sorry but that isn't grub that's broken, it seems like the linux installation itself is broken