# Ubuntu 18.04 boots too slow on lenovo ideapad 320

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, lenovo, plymouth

I have Lenovo Ideapad 320 with i5 7th gen, NVIDIA 920mx 2 GB, 8 GB ram.

Ubuntu takes like - 1:00 min to 1:30 min to boot, and my 10 year old Dell Inspiron 1440 boots Windows 10 faster than it!

Some notes:

- Fastboot unabled
- SATA mode to ACHI
- Single boot
- It shows blank purple screen before ubuntu loading logo.

**dmesg**(only ones which take long)

```
[    7.700100] systemd-journald[245]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    7.733583] Adding 2097148k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:6 across:2260988k FS
[    7.939799] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   25.470553] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[   25.470555] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[   25.470556] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[   25.470558] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found


[   37.592140] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   40.718766] wlp3s0: authenticate with 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5
[   40.719207] wlp3s0: send auth to 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5 (try 1/3)

[   40.761674] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5
[   40.854572] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   65.119742] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized

[  395.759338] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  397.941735] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[  397.941736] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  399.018517] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  399.059635] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[  399.061727] OOM killer disabled.
[  399.061728] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  399.062989] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  399.220749] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  399.249021] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  400.190865] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[  400.290845] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  400.291415] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[  400.291416] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[  400.291416] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  400.291489] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  400.306547] IRQ 129: no longer affine to CPU1
[  400.307557] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[  400.330526] IRQ 130: no longer affine to CPU2
[  400.331928] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[  400.354437] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU3
[  400.354441] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU3
[  400.354444] IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU3
[  400.354447] IRQ 127: no longer affine to CPU3
[  400.355457] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[18446744059.118911] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: CPU0 0 --> -372692035. Restoring
[  400.358296] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[  400.358425] ACPI: EC: EC started
[  400.358426] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[  400.365100] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  400.365144] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[  400.365145] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[  400.367969]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[  400.368151] CPU1 is up
[  400.368173] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[  400.368645]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[  400.368799] CPU2 is up
[  400.368827] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[  400.369193]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[  400.369350] CPU3 is up
[  400.372292] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  400.376767] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[  400.683681] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[  400.683952] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[  400.688057] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  400.727973] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[  400.917617] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  401.000180] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[  401.004740] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  401.194127] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  401.344099] acpi LNXPOWER:14: Turning OFF
[  401.344217] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[  401.344331] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[  401.344444] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[  401.344556] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[  401.344670] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[  401.344782] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[  401.344896] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[  401.345009] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[  401.345141] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[  401.345257] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[  401.345374] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[  401.345490] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[  401.345603] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[  401.345715] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[  401.345828] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
[  401.345942] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[  401.346055] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[  401.346168] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[  401.346283] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[  401.346372] OOM killer enabled.
[  401.346373] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  401.351976] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000a lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8821
[  401.351978] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
[  401.351992] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin failed with error -2
[  401.351994] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
[  401.352614] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[  401.352619] Bluetooth: hci0: cfg_sz 0, total size 17428
[  401.354619] [drm] RC6 on
[  401.445209] PM: suspend exit
[  401.577367] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  401.904840] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  401.991070] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  402.377782] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[  402.422938] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[  402.423036] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[  402.426424] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  402.746924] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  402.786740] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  405.908971] wlp3s0: authenticate with 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5
[  405.909414] wlp3s0: send auth to 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5 (try 1/3)
[  405.911301] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  405.918890] wlp3s0: associate with 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5 (try 1/3)
[  405.922642] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  405.922976] wlp3s0: associated
[  405.972876] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 32:07:4d:10:1e:d5
[  405.979914] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
```

**systemd-analyze blame**

```
 24.471s dev-sda2.device
 22.539s systemd-journal-flush.service
 16.281s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
 16.129s keyboard-setup.service
 15.032s systemd-sysctl.service
 12.042s plymouth-quit-wait.service
  6.979s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  5.891s dev-loop20.device
  5.755s snapd.service
  5.172s bolt.service
  4.855s dev-loop8.device
  4.461s dev-loop9.device
  4.454s dev-loop13.device
  4.453s dev-loop11.device
  4.443s dev-loop14.device
  4.427s dev-loop17.device
  4.427s dev-loop15.device
  4.412s dev-loop18.device
  4.386s dev-loop22.device
  4.363s dev-loop24.device
  4.347s dev-loop25.device
  4.253s dev-loop23.device
  4.202s dev-loop1.device
```

Few questions :

- What are dev-loops and how to get rid of them?
- Why keyboard setup is taking 16s?
- performance of hard-drive?

I am new to linux but, I've gone through the following questions but didn't find them useful.

- [Ubuntu 18.04 too slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037668/ubuntu-18-04-too-slow)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 boots slowly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032086/ubuntu-18-04-boots-slowly)
- [What happens if I disable and uninstall Plymouth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136280/what-happens-if-i-disable-and-uninstall-plymouth)

Comment: I'm not convinced that Comar's answer, really answered your question, and really provided an actionable solution. Please tell me what you actually did to solve your problem, if it's actually solved. Thanks! Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Well after disabling plymouth,systemd-journal-flush and fixing keyboard setup service, now my laptop is booting arround 35-45s which is significant

Comment: Thanks for the update. Rather than disabling parts of your system, I'd have suggested that you replace your snap applications with regular applications, and that would also trim down your boot time. See `snap list` to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu, as any other OS, can slow down over time, because of data, logs and software stored on your PC. And it's good thing to simply clean it from time time, i.e. remove old logs, caches and software you don't need or use anymore.

However essentially your hard drive is the bottleneck here.

But also systemd is doing things that are just slow on old hard drives. This is one of the reasons why some people (including me) complain on systemd, because it tries to do everything, but not always do it well.

Fortunately, you can deal with systemd services by disabling or delaying them.

You can read about it here:

- [What is the use of systemd-journal-flush.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service)

> What are dev-loops and how to get rid of them?

dev-loops are used for snaps mounting points, the more snaps are installed, the more loop devices will be spawned during boot.

However you should know that not all of the services shown in systemd-analyze will block your from being able to use your PC, as some of them are delayed to be done after desktop environment is ready.

> Why keyboard setup is taking 16s?

Check this answer:

- [keyboard-setup.service taking too long in startup (20+sec)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919428/keyboard-setup-service-taking-too-long-in-startup-20sec?rq=1)

> performance of hard-drive?

That's the main issue. These days Ubuntu is much heavier and requires more resources to work efficiently.

> and my 10 year old Dell Inspiron 1440 boots Windows 10 faster than it!

Keep in mind that on notebooks Windows 10 most of the time is not fully shut down. It uses functions like hibernation to save its state to hard drive and speed up next boot, even if you think you've powered it down. Of course knowing this don't change anything for you. It still has better boot times, over Ubuntu, but it's not always true, especially after updates.

Comment: Thanks you really solved many of my issues!

Comment: One Last Question :- What is "wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found"?  it took nearly 18s

Comment: The fact that these messages shown after 25 seconds from start, doesn't mean that they are somehow related to boot time. It's rather because something invoked at this point printing them out, meaning you can ignore them and rather focus on what systemd-analyze tells you.